# How to indent a header?

Tags: html, css

I have a border around my `h4` header :

```
h4 {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: gray;
  width: 90%;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

which renders as

[image]

I would like to indent the whole header (including the border) by `50px`. Adding `text-indent: 50px;` indents just the text, not the border (and `border-indent` apparently does not exist)

[image]

What should be done so that the border is indented as well (or is indented, dragging the text within)?

Comment: have you tried `margin-left`?

Comment: used to padding-left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `margin`:

```
h4 {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: gray;
  width: 90%;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 50px; /* change this as you like */
}
```

`margin` will shift the whole element while `padding` will increase the space between the content and the border.

Look at this picture to understand the difference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin-left` property to move the border also for `h4` tag

Check out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/va92nx2t/)

**CSS:**

```
h4 {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: gray;
  width: 90%;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a wrapper:

```
h4 {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
#wrapper {
    width:90%;
    padding-left:12px
}


<div id="wrapper">
<h4>ddd</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-left: 50px` and a `margin-left: 50px` to the h4

```
h4 {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: gray;
  width: 90%;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 50px; /*top, right, bottom, left*/
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

The padding will affect the space between the border and the content, while the margin the space between the container and the nearest element

Comment: `padding-left` does not move the border (just the text inside)

Comment: Use `margin-left` too if you want the border to move.

Padding refers to the content, margin is like "outside of the box"

Comment: @MattiaNocerino `Padding-left` is not the solution. Kindly update the answer

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. I was reading the question but i was paying more attention to the image than the text itself

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
h4 {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: gray;
  width: 90%;
  border-style: solid;
  padding:5px;
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/gek8h9t0/2/)

Comment: `padding-left` does not move the border (just the text inside)

Comment: Padding-left is not the solution. Kindly remove it from your answer

Comment: Thanks sir @Gunaseelan